# Find the vector equation for the line passing through two points

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is find the vector equation for the line passing through two points P1 = (6,2,4) and P2 = (12,0,3)
But the formatting of the answer is throwing me off. Should I just find the difference between these two points?

The answer format is as follows:
[x,y,z] = [0,0,0] + t[0,0,0]

Comment: No evidence of work done!

Comment: In the "answer format" there is a base point (points and vectors are somewhat interchangeable, though it sometimes makes sense to distinguish the *roles* they play) and an offset *vector* which takes the scalar multiple $t$.  Neither the base point nor the offset vector is unique, which makes it possible to have correct answers in the same format that are not obviously equivalent without a slight bit of computation.  I wonder if you have difficulty in "checking" your answer against "the one in the book" because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented as $\vec{x} = \vec{u} + t \vec{v}$, where $\vec{u}, \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are some constants and $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ are variables. This form captures a linear relationship between the variables, i.e. in each unit of $t$, all variables grow in the same proportion, governed by $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{u}$ is used to translate the line passing through the origin to allow it to pass through any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In your case, 2 points are given, $P = (6,2,4)$ and $Q = (12, 0, 3)$. How fast $t$ changes is not important, since it does not alter the relative rates of change of the individual variables. So $\vec{v}$ measuring change will be given by $$\vec{v} = \vec{Q} - \vec{P} = (6, -2, -1)$$ and now the line looks like $$(x,y,z) = \vec{u} + t (6,-2,-1).$$

You need to pick $\vec{u}$ so that the line passes through both $P$ and $Q$. If we make it pass through one of them, it will automatically pass through the other one since that was the whole idea of fixing $\vec{v}$.

So let's make it pass through $\vec{P}$. To do that, note that when $t = 0$, we have $(x,y,z) = \vec{u}$, i.e., the line always passes through $\vec{u}$, no matter which values you pick for it. So letting $\vec{u} = \vec{P}$ we end up with the general equation
$$
\vec{x} = \vec{P} + t \left( \vec{Q} - \vec{P} \right),
$$
which in our case yields
$$
(x,y,z) = (6,2,4) + t (6, -2, -1)
$$
which is equivalent to simultaneous equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 6+6t\\
y = 2-2t\\
z = 4-t
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score -2):

You just apply the formula:
$$M=P_1+t \,\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}\quad (t\in\mathbf R),$$
where the coordinates of $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}$ are very simply the difference of the coordinates of $P_2$ and $P_1$.

Comment: Ok so I got  L (the answer) = [6,2,4]  + t[-6,2,1]  so basically the first vector plus t multiplied by the distance between the two vectors

Comment: More exactly, it's $t$ times the difference of the vectors, i.e. $t$ times the translation which brings $P_1$ to $P_2$..