# How to find the vector equation of a line

Tags: vector-spaces

I recently learnt of the formula 'r = p + λu' to work out vector equations but I'm having trouble applying it when there are no values to work with. Take this example:

Let A, B, C be three points with position vectors a, b, c respectively. You may assume that the three points A, B, C do not all lie on the same straight line.

Let D, E, F be the midpoints of the line-segments BC, AC, AB respectively.

Since vectors are new to me, I'll probably be downvoted 49 times but here goes my attempt:

I want to find the vector equation of the line running through A and D. My initial approach is to let p be the point A, and u be the non-zero vector AD. Working out AD, I get (-a,-0.5b,0.5c). I don't really know where to go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the formula
suggest that the line is passing through $p$ and it is perpendicular to $u$.
The thing you did is right, since it should be passing through AD you need that vector equation.
Thus is passing through A and something $\lambda$ times the vector AD.
For the exact answer, you need to put the values and solve for $\lambda$.
Check this out

[Find the vector equation for the line passing through two points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615396/find-the-vector-equation-for-the-line-passing-through-two-points)